# Loop through rows with conditions

Tags: list, forms, loops, google-sheets

A simple question to loop through a list with a condition to extract a list...
Here is my code. I would like to simply ask if in column 7 i have the letter "P" then it adds the name in column 6 to the list... Thanks a lot !

```
function setfieldsdefaults() {

var form = FormApp.openById('mygoogleformsID')
var items = form.getItems();

//for (var i in items) {
//  console.log(items[i].getTitle() + ' - ' + items[i].getId())
// }

var question = form.getItemById('myquestionID');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('mysreadsheetID');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Abonnés');
var range = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
var enfants = range.getValues();
enfants = enfants.flat();
enfants = enfants.filter(row => row !=='');
enfants = enfants.sort()
console.log(enfants);}
```

I am starting to code, but honestly quite far away from my small knowledges in VBA...

Thanks a million!
Etienne

I someone could help that would be very nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You could `.filter` to keep only the rows with a "P", and `.map` to extract just the column you want

Just add the following at the end of your existing function:

```
const names = enfants.filter(enfant=>enfant[6]==="P").map(enfant=>enfant[5])
```

Here I am assuming your "column 7" is counting from 1.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why couldn't I add this (I just wanted to keep "enfants" and not add "names" :  'enfants = enfants.filter(enfants=>enfants[9]==="P").map(enfants=>enfants[6])' ? "Enfants" are under column F, and my search if "P" in front of "enfants" is in column I. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :)

I just had to adapt the below code from:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
```

to

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow(),5);
```

My mistake was to take only 1 column, without the column containing "P"...

Then I just had to adapt to:

```
enfants = enfants.filter(enfant=>enfant[5]==="P").map(enfant=>enfant[0])
```

Thanks for the tips :) Took me some times to resolve it, but now I understand the logic.

Thanks again!
E.

Comment: I do suggest though, that you don't re-use the same variable name for a different _kind_ of thing. Each `enfant` is an entire object, containing name and other information. In contrast, the output of your line is list of _just_ names, not objects. It is in your interests as a programmer to use a different variable name for data of a different type.